# Lookup helper not firing after records inserted via trigger, but does fire after update

Tags: lookup, before-trigger

Issue: lookup helper is not firing on insert, but is firing on update. How can I ensure that the lookups are fired on inserted records, and not just updated records?

Steps taken:
Using a webhook to capture data from a third party. I have verified that I am receiving the data I expect, and transposing this data into a custom object is successful. The lookup is only firing on update, but not on insert.
I'm setting the following on insert within the trigger:

```
issue.Assignee_Jira_AccountId__c = obj.fields.assignee != null ? obj.fields.assignee.accountId : null;
issue.Creator_Jira_AccountId__c = obj.fields.creator != null ? obj.fields.creator.accountId : null;
issue.Architect_Jira_AccountId__c = obj.fields.architect != null ? obj.fields.architect.accountId : null;
issue.Reporter_Jira_AccountId__c = obj.fields.reporter != null ? obj.fields.reporter.accountId : null;
```

and using the lookup helper to populate a different field on the same custom object.
-field level security is set to visible: true for all the custom fields
-the lookup succeeds when I edit/update the object
How can I get lookup helper to fire after the insert succeeds?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] for getting the most from the Community. 
 Presumably you are talking about the [Lookup Helper appexchange package](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wj3REAQ)? Have you contacted the vendor?

Comment: So have you run into this issue or not? is this an issue with the timing of the trigger completing or with LH itself?